# How to draw a ggplot2 boxplot with precalculated stats in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get a boxplot for a precalculated dataset.  The dataset already contains the min, max, median, 10th percentile, and 90th percentile for a response time test I ran.  Is there anyway to product a ggplot2 boxplot from this?

I've included a sample of the dateset.

Thank you,

```
throughput <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
response_time_min <- c(9, 19, 29, 39, 49)
response_time_10  <- c(50, 55, 60, 60, 61)
response_time_med <- c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
response_time_90  <- c(201, 201, 250, 200, 230)
response_time_max <- c(401, 414, 309, 402, 311)
df <- data.frame(throughput, response_time_min, response_time_10, response_time_med, response_time_90, response_time_max)
df
throughput response_time_min response_time_10 response_time_med response_time_90 response_time_max
1          1                 9               50               100              201               401
2          2                19               55               100              201               414
3          3                29               60               100              250               309
4          4                39               60               100              200               402
5          5                49               61               100              230               311
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Search for "precomputed stat" in the [official documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(throughput),
                 ymax = response_time_max,
                 upper = response_time_90,
                 y = response_time_med,
                 middle = response_time_med, 
                 lower = response_time_10, 
                 ymin = response_time_min), stat = "identity")
```